# After i run the server i get "No module named 'crispy_forms'" message?

Tags: django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I have tried to installed django-crispy-forms ;however, i got this error: ImportError: No module named 'crispy_forms'

Ps. i needed to install with -sudo..

thank you

Comment: Are you using virtualenv? How did you install `django-crispy-forms`?

Comment: Yes i installed in virtualenv.

Comment: Why did you need sudo? Did you activate the virtualenv before installing?

Comment: Yes it was activated. It tried to install with sudo because  i was getting ' permission denied' messages.

Comment: Is the problem only related to crispy-forms? Do other modules work? Is `crispy_forms` in your *virtualenv* `site-packages`?

Comment: I can see  it in the site packages folder. I dont have any other issue, as far i know.